# return null in mysql procedure with dynamic query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

can someone please tell me what I am missing I have invested 4 hours and watch lots of article can't figure out why is showing return null

mysql mysql procedure is as follows.

```
create  procedure proc_studymaterial_listing(
    get_exam_id int(11)
)
begin
    set @query1 = concat( "select c.content_type, 
                                  c.title, 
                                  c.status, 
                                  c.created_on, 
                                  c.pdf_is_downloadable, 
                                  a.content_id, 
                                  a.expiry_date, 
                                  exam_Name,  
                                  fun_subject_name(a.subject_id) as subject_name, 
                                  fun_subject_name(a.chapter_id) as chapter_name
                           from  tbl_studymaterial_exam_chapter_map as a 
                           join tbl_exam_master as b on a.exam_id= b.exam_ID
                           join tbl_studymaterial as c on c.id= a.content_id  
                           where c.status=1 " );

    if( get_exam_id = 0 ) 
    then
        set @exam_id = " and 1=1 ";
    else
        set @exam_id = concat( ' and  b.exam_ID = " ', @get_exam_id , '"' );
    end if;     

    SET @final_query =  CONCAT ( @query1,@exam_id );    

    PREPARE stmt FROM @final_query ; 
    # select stmt; 
    # EXECUTE stmt;
    #  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

end;
```

Comment: Replace `PREPARE` statement with `SELECT @final_query;` and show the output. PS. `get_exam_id` is `int(11)` - why you quote it with dquote chars as it is a string?

Answer (score 1):

User-defined variable `@get_exam_id` doesn't appear to be assigned a value anywhere. If that's not assigned a non-NULL value, then the result of evaluating this line:

```
set @exam_id = concat( ' and  b.exam_ID = " ', @get_exam_id , '"' );
```

is that `@exam_id` will be NULL. And that will cascade into the next CONCAT, which will also evaluate to NULL.

---

User-defined variables start with an `@` at sign character.

Those are distinct and separate from procedure arguments and variables, which do not start with an `@` at sign character.

---

Looks like maybe the intent was to reference the local variable `get_exam_id`, not a user-defined variable.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Personally, if I had to write the body of the procedure, I'd do it something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_studymaterial_listing( get_exam_id INT(11))
BEGIN
   SET @sql = CONCAT( 'SELECT c.content_type'
              ,'\n'  ,'     , c.title'
              ,'\n'  ,'     , c.status' 
              ,'\n'  ,'     , c.created_on' 
              ,'\n'  ,'     , c.pdf_is_downloadable' 
              ,'\n'  ,'     , a.content_id' 
              ,'\n'  ,'     , a.expiry_date' 
              ,'\n'  ,'     , b.exam_name'
              ,'\n'  ,'     , fun_subject_name(a.subject_id)  AS subject_name'
              ,'\n'  ,'     , fun_subject_name(a.chapter_id)  AS chapter_name'
              ,'\n'  ,'  FROM tbl_studymaterial_exam_chapter_map a' 
              ,'\n'  ,'  JOIN tbl_exam_master b'
              ,'\n'  ,'    ON b.exam_id = a.exam_id'
              ,'\n'  ,'  JOIN tbl_studymaterial c'
              ,'\n'  ,'    ON c.id = a.content_id'
              ,'\n'  ,' WHERE c.status = 1'
              ,'\n'
              ,CASE
                 WHEN get_exam_id <> 0
                 THEN '   AND b.exam_id = ? '
                 ELSE ''
               END
              ,'\n'  ,' ORDER BY subject_name, chapter_name, exam_name'
              );
   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
   IF (get_exam_id <> 0) THEN
      SET @id = get_exam_id;
      EXECUTE stmt USING @id;
      SET @id = '';
   ELSE
      EXECUTE stmt;
   END IF;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
   SET @sql = '';
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```